# Is it possible to process X amount of streaming API streams with multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-requests

I would like to be able to use the multiprocessing library in python to continuously stream from multiple live web apis with python-request (Using the Stream option). Would this be possible on a dual-core Linux system or am I better off running them as single programs in multiple screen sessions?

Would I also want to use a pool of workers?

Thank you for the help, let me know if the question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Figure out what your bottleneck is going to be before designing a solution;

The first thing to look at is probably network bandwith. If one stream can saturate your network, downloading more than one toghether won't be faster.

The second thing is disk write throughput. Can your disk and OS handle all these concurrent writes?

If you want to do transcoding, you might also run into computational limits.

Comment: I don't believe latency will be a bottleneck (Internal Company systems). As far as disk throughput, the goal of the program is to monitor different streams for a specific event string that might happen (The API is acting as a live event dump). The only time disk I/O will happen is when a match is discovered. Then a small amount of file IO will happen. Python-requests will be parsing data on a line-by-line basis. I just want to know if its possible to have many of these operations going on at once and at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using `multiprocessing` will let you stream from multiple APIs.  You want to use a `Pool`, because it simplifies getting data back and forth.

Here's a simple example:

### source

```
import multiprocessing

def calc(num):
    return num*2

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(5)
for output in pool.map(calc, [1,2,3]):
    print 'output:',output
```

### output

```
output: 2
output: 4
output: 6
```

Comment: In a case like this the last thing you want to do is to shuffle huge amounts of data from child process to parent. Workers should write the streams to disk, and they should only return a status indicator.

Comment: Thanks guys. Will I have to worry about locking pool threads for I/O? Or will python handle this for me? The only time I/O will occur is when a string match is found. The API is working as a live event dump.

Comment: You don't have to worry about locking for I/O using a `Pool`